# iPhone not rendering the page properly when centering a page while having the header and footer at 100% width

Tags: html, css, wrapper

got what should be an easy one here. Apparently not for me, though.

Essentially, I'm developing a site, (unfortunately, i can't provide a link) and the design calls for a header and footer that spans 100%, while all content within the page (including content in the header and footer) span only 940px and are centered in a wrapper.

The basic page setup i am using is this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="headerwrap">
      CONTENT HERE...
    </div>
</div>

<div id="contentwrapper">

     MAIN PAGE CONTENT HERE...

</div>

<div id="footer">
     <div class="footerwrap">
        FOOTER CONTENT HERE...
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I am using as well:

```
.footerwrap {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:940px;
}

 .headerwrap {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:940px;
}

.contentwrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:940px;
}

#header, #footer {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

This works perfectly in a browser, but on the iPhone, it pushes all content to the left of the page, and only lets the images in the header and footer span about 200px when they are supposed to be spanning the entire page.

Here is an example of what it's supposed to look like:

[image: ex1]

And here is an example of what it looks like on the iPhone.

[image: ex2]

Comment: Please provide a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) or [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of what you are trying to do that I've tested on iPhone.

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
html,body{width:100%;}
header, footer {width:100%; height:200px;background:black;}
div{width:960px; height:500px; background:gray; margin:0 auto;}
```

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1927422)